# Nvidia driver resolution

Tags: nvidia

I have to reinstall the nvidia drivers upon every reboot. The resolution is only correct on the first boot,  after that I cannot change it and it looks to be 320x??.

GPU: Geforce 750Ti
OS: 18.04
Driver: doesn't matter tried 390 and 435, same behaviour

nomodeset enabled, doesn't boot otherwise
I use this on every boot and it works but is inconvient: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* -y && sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-435 -y && reboot`

Answer (score 0):

Take this advice with caution, as it may not be entirely the best, but I found someone with your similar issue and they said this helped:

"Hi all, and I apologize for the late response. I was away for a few days.
Thank you to jschiwal and Electro for your help. While I tried your solutions (they did not work), I accidentally did stumble upon the source of the problem and the solution. It turns out that there was a single nvidia script (/etc/rc2.d/S20nvidia-glx) that was the root cause of all this headache. Simply changing its permissions to not allow it to be executed fixed the problem. Hopefully this post will show up on the google search of the next guy who's having to reinstall the driver after each reboot."

What I took from this was that there might be a script that has a line in it that causes this issue, if someone else can verify that would be great, but if you feel comfortable with it, feel free to check this.

Comment: I have no such file. Ran 'sudo find /etc -name \*nvidia\*'